How can I structure my Python package/submodules so I do not get a circular import error?
Before marking as duplicate to this one, please look at the details of my layout.  I've gone through and this question does not address my issue and I haven't been able to adapt the answer:
ImportError: cannot import name '...' from partially initialized module '...' (most likely due to a circular import)
Here's my package layout:
clairvoyance
|-- __init__.py
|-- bayesian
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- bayesian.py
|-- legacy
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- legacy.py
|-- utils
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- utils.py
`-- visuals
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- visuals.py

5 directories, 9 files

Here's the relevant files:

clairvoyance/__init__.py

__version__ = "2024.6.17"

from . import bayesian
from . import legacy
from . import utils
from . import visuals


clairvoyance/bayesian/__init__.py

from .bayesian import *


clairvoyance/legacy/__init__.py

from .legacy import *


clairvoyance/utils/__init__.py

from .utils import *


clairvoyance/visuals/__init__.py

from .visuals import *

In terms of relative imports, I have the following:

utils.py None
bayesian.py has from ..utils import *
legacy has from ..utils import * and from ..visuals import *
visuals.py has from ..utils import *

I made sure there are no blatant circular imports so I have a feeling it has to do with the way I've structured my submodules.
I'm getting the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'bayesian' from partially initialized module 'clairvoyance' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/jolespin/miniconda3/envs/soothsayer_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clairvoyance/__init__.py)


I don't know if your current setup is a temporary one before you complicate the subpackages with additional files, but if you expect it to stay the same way, there's no need for the subpackages. Just move bayesian.py, legacy.py, visual.py and util.py into the clairvoyance folder and it will all work the same way, without any of the folders and extra __init__.py files. I'm not sure if this is related to your circular reference issue, but it would simplify debugging.

That just fixed it. Thank you!

@Blckknght can you write an answer saying this. Also changing from ..utils to from .utils.  I'll mark it as correct.
